# auto complete and mod_evasive

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, ddos, mod-evasive

One friend told me that my site is vulnerable to DDos or Slowloris attacks. I ask him what i can do about it. And he suggested **mod_evasive**, now here is my questions.

1 ) Is this enough to protect me?

2 ) I install the and set the **mod_evasive** and everything is working but now I have some problems with the ajax requests. I have a autocomplete friend mention like in twitter **@username** and i made it when the textarea is on keyup and when there is more then 3 symbols after **@** to make an ajax requests and show some friends names. The problem is that when there are more than 4 symbols after **@** it makes too many requests and the user is blocked for some time. How can that be fixed?

Comment: what is the web server you are using? Ddos meaning many things are you interesting about preventing Slowloris(uses specific technique) specifically? Do you use any firewall?

Comment: no i dont use any firewall or slowloris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty old question, but I just ran into this problem too. You can solve this issue by editing **"mod-evasive.conf"** file.

```
<ifmodule mod_evasive20.c>
   DOSHashTableSize 3097
   DOSPageCount  20
   DOSSiteCount  100
   DOSPageInterval 1
   DOSSiteInterval  1
   DOSBlockingPeriod  10
   DOSLogDir   /var/log/mod_evasive
   DOSEmailNotify  email@dom.com
   DOSWhitelist   127.0.0.1
</ifmodule>
```

You have to play around with **"DOSPageCount"** and **"DOSPageInterval"**. You should find the harmony between legal ajax calls and ddos attacks. Im sure there are some more professional solutions to fix this problem like giving exceptions for ajax files but I had no time yet to look around for more information. I hope it helps...